# When is destructor called in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, session, destructor

I need to create a service which will maintain a WCF session.
In the constructor I read in data from the DB and when the session ends I have to save it back.

If I understand correctly the session ends when I call Close() on the Client (My client ServiceClient was created with SvcUtil.exe).

When I test it I see that it is sometimes called after approx. 10 minutes, sometimes after 20 minutes and sometimes not at all.

So when is the destructor called?

Service

```
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
   public class Service:IService
   {
     private User m_User = null;

     public  Service()
     {
       m_User = User.LoadFromDB();
     }

     ~Service()
     {
       m_User.SaveToDB();
     }

     public void SetName(string p_Name)
     {
       m_User.Name = p_Name;
     }
    }
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      <services>
        <service name="Karatasi.Services.B2C"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:19401/B2C.svc"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        <endpoint
           address=""
           binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="test"
           contract="Karatasi.Services.IB2C"
         />
        <endpoint
           address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange"
         />
       </service>
     </services>
   <bindings>
     <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="test" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" >
         <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="00:01:00"/>
       </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client

```
    ServiceClient serviceClient = null;
    try
    {
      serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
      serviceClient.SetName("NewName");
      Console.WriteLine("Name set");
    }
    catch (Exception p_Exc)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(p_Exc.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
      if (serviceClient != null)
      {
        if (serviceClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
          serviceClient.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
          serviceClient.Close();
        }
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: First of all this is completely wrong service design.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> The programmer has no control over when the destructor is called
>   because this is determined by the garbage collector. The garbage
>   collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the
>   application. If it considers an object eligible for destruction, it
>   calls the destructor (if any) and reclaims the memory used to store
>   the object. Destructors are also called when the program exits.

There is a problem with your implementation. To persist data you are using destructor. This is wrong because destructors cannot be called deterministically, they are processed in a separate finalization queue. This means that even though you have destroyed the object, its destructor may not be immediately called.

**How to fix this**
Remove the destructor and use IDisposable pattern instead, put save logic into Dispose. Once the session is terminated, WCF will call IDisposable.Dispose

```
public class Service:IService, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //your save logic here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Pls also see the comment to this answer. I actually agree that `IDisposable` isn't the proper place for database commits, didn't occur to me before. Additionally to the solutions provided in the comment you can use [explicit session demarcation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Sessions_in_WCF.aspx)

Comment: No! Don't put it in `IDisposable.Dispose` either! `IDisposable.Dispose` is for cleaning up managed resources. Saving to a database is not cleaning up a managed resource. This goes against the *accepted* and *expected* usage of this interface. Either make `SetName` commit the changes to the database, or provide another method on the service `Commit`. Also, minor quibble, in C# we call it a "finalizer." Yes, confusion abounds on this topic.