# Can I override Dispose to make an entity class that always calls SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, finalizer, object-lifetime

This is a fairly fine point, and I expect the answer is "it's not a hot idea to begin with" - that said, it has a points that I'm interested in regardless, if someone is kind enough to indulge.

Model Code:

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
{
    // the idea is if the object is in a using block, this always gets called?
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
using(var model = new MyEntities())
{
   // do something

   // no worry about calling model.SaveChanges()
}
```

The issues I'm uncertain about are:

1. Is Dispose the right place to do this because I was thinking "Finalize" for some reason - I always get confused on C# destruction.
2. In the case an exception is thrown in the client code, ordinarily SaveChanges would be skipped and that's good, but if this works how I think, it'll always call it.  Should I use try with an empty catch?

   ```
   public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
   {
       protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           try
           {
              this.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch {}
           base.Dispose(disposing);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: -1 Dispose is for cleaning up resources. Calling SaveChanges there is very bad.

Comment: is it's invocation tied to the scope of the containing stack frame or tied to the garbage collector? that's what I think I was really wondering now that you made me think more.

Comment: You can't let anybody see this code.  However, the neckshot is that you'll call SaveChanges() even when the code throws an exception.  That's a great way to mess up a dbase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a Class to disk on dispose: Does my code have bugs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832911/saving-a-class-to-disk-on-dispose-does-my-code-have-bugs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't do this. It's a bad idea.

The purpose of "Dispose" is to *politely* dispose of an unmanaged resource early so that other processes can use it.  "Dispose" should not have *semantics* -- it should not change the state of your program or be required in some way. It should only do precisely what it says it does: *dispose of a resource*.

Should you do it in the finalizer?  *Absolutely not*. That's even worse. The finalizer might not run at all, the finalizer runs on another thread, the finalizer can be called even if the object wasn't properly initialized, and so on. **Writing a finalizer is almost never the right thing to do, and if you do write a finalizer it should only dispose of a resource.** Do not do anything fancy in a finalizer; you will almost certainly write a dangerously incorrect and brittle program if you do.

The right principle to cleave to here is: **if a call is required for semantic reasons then force the user to put the call in the code.**  If they forget to do it, they'll find out in testing. **Let the user decide whether it is the right thing to do to put the call in a finally block or not.** Don't make that decision for them; you might decide wrong.

Comment: Similar question and unfortunate accepted answer that does not point out that this should not be done in `IDisposable.Dispose` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295198/when-is-destructor-called-in-a-wcf-service/7295325#comment-8790533).

Comment: @Greg, i started out a C++ programmer from '96 to '01... C# ever since.. I've been profiled correctly

Answer (score 0):

1. Dispose is where you would do this, if you were to do it at all.
2. This is one of the reasons you should *not* do it.

Comment: i suppose a programming language could conceivably have a "success block" control structure

Comment: That's what OO and architecture is for. Create a class that has an extensible "success block" but is perhaps defined with some base functionality in your abstract class.